# how can I specify the version of Python to use in an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a project that is still running Python 2.  I'm trying to use Ansible to set up new test servers.  The base Linux installation that I start with only has Python 3, so I need my very first "bootstrap" playbook to use Python 3, but then I want subsequent playbooks to use Python 2.

I can specify the version of python in my inventory file like this:

```
[test_server:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

[test_server]
test_server.example.com
```

But then I have to go edit the inventory file to make sure that I'm using Python 3 for the bootstrap playbook, and then edit it again for the rest of my playbooks.  That seems odd.  I've tried a few different versions of changing `ansible_python_interpreter` within my playbooks, like

```
- hosts: test_server
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
```

and

```
- hosts: test_server
  tasks:
    - name: install pip
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
      apt:
        name: python-pip
```

but ansible complains that

> ERROR! 'ansible_python_interpreter' is not a valid attribute for a Task

Even though https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html says that

> You can still set ansible_python_interpreter to a specific path at any variable level (for example, in host_vars, in vars files, in playbooks, etc.).

What's the invocation to do this correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Q: ***"What's the invocation to do this correctly?"***

```yaml
- hosts: test_server
  tasks:
    - name: install pip
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
      apt:
        name: python-pip
```

> ERROR! 'ansible_python_interpreter' is not a valid attribute for a Task

---

A: *ansible_python_interpreter* is not a [Playbook keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). It is a [variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html#using-python-3-on-the-managed-machines-with-commands-and-playbooks) and must be declared as such. For example, in the scope of a task

```yaml
- hosts: test_server
  tasks:
    - name: install pip
      apt:
        name: python-pip
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
```

, or in the scope of a play

```yaml
- hosts: test_server
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
  tasks:
    - name: install pip
      apt:
        name: python-pip
```

, or in any other suitable place. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

---

See:

- [INTERPRETER_PYTHON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python)
- [INTERPRETER_PYTHON_FALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python-fallback)

Notes:

- Quoting from [Changelog core 2.14](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/stable-2.14/changelogs/fragments/hide_distro_map.yml):

> configuration entry INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP is now 'private' and won't show up in normal configuration queries and docs, since it is not 'settable' this avoids user confusion.

- Search `_INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP` in [ansible/lib/ansible/config/base.yml](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/config/base.yml) to see current value of INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP